# Python script to check if current IP address is from DHCP or static

Tags: networking, python, application-development, dhcp

How to check if eth address is taken from DHCP or set manually (static) using Python?

Comment: This similar question (near duplicate) may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47873/check-if-ip-is-static-or-dynamic-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

I think it's going to depend on how the network is configured. Network connections in Ubuntu are either configured for the computer, or by the individual user through [Network Manager](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/) (that little network icon in your notification area). Servers are generally configured system-wide from `/etc`, while desktops are configured by Network Manager.

If it's a system-wide configuration, you can parse `/etc/network/interfaces`.

If the network was configured by Network Manager on the desktop, you can interface with it. You can find an example Python script that prints connections from the [Network Manager examples](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/examples/python/list-connections.py).

There might be a lower-level way of finding out whether any particular interface is dhcp, but I don't know of it.