# Syntax error in awk program

Tags: networking, scripts, awk

I want to check the method of IP-Assignment as in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47873/check-if-ip-is-static-or-dynamic-programmatically) question. I'm running it in bash on Ubuntu 12.04.
My Problem is the function "get_con_id()" gives me "Syntax error" at the if-clause.
The script is as following(unmodified from the answer in the given question):

```
 #!/bin/sh

 # get the connection id of the active connection    
 get_con_id() {
   nm-tool |
     awk '
       $1 == "-" {
         dev = $3
         id = dev
         if (NF > 4 && match($0, "\\[(.*)\\]", a))
           id = a[1]
       }
       /^ / && $1 == "State:" && $2 == "connected" {
         print id
       }'
 }

 # get the address type of the active connection
 nmcli con list id "$(get_con_id)" |
   awk '
     $1 == "ipv4.method:" {
       if ($2 == "manual")
         print "static"
       else if ($2 == "auto")
         print "dynamic"
       else
         print "unknown"
     }'
```

Comment: Exactly, it is just copied, but I can't comment the old thread without reputation. I copied it in a file named test.sh and ran ./test.sh. When I give an ID to the script and don't use the function it works.

Comment: It look like it works, for me at least in a terminal. How are you executing this code?

Comment: Of course, the script is executable and the lower part works, if I replace `nmcli con list id "$(get_con_id)"` with `nmcli con list id "<anNetID>"` the script returns static or dynamic. the problem is the upper part (the function get_con_id()) - it gives me `awk: line 5: syntax error at or near ,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `mawk` but this script requires `gawk`.

```
sudo apt-get install gawk
```

It will automatically reset `awk` to `gawk` so the script will work. If it won't reset, then just change every `awk` in the script to `gawk`.